# awk perl grep pattern match ignoring

Tags: perl, awk, while-loop, grep

I have a file with about 100,000 lines that look more of less like this:

```
if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*55555.*"){
             rewritehostport("10.10.10.2:1337");
             rewritehostport("10.20.30.2:2345");
             sl_send_reply("302", "Redirect");
             exit;
     }
     if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*4444.*"){
             rewritehostport("10.10.10.2:1337");
             rewritehostport("10.20.30.2:2345");
             sl_send_reply("302", "Redirect");
             exit;
     }
     if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*3333.*"){
             rewritehostport("10.10.10.2:1337");
             rewritehostport("10.20.30.2:2345");
             sl_send_reply("302", "Redirect");
             exit;
     }
```

I am looking for a method to selective ignore a variable (say 55555) along with the lines up until the curly bracket }

`awk '/proto/{a=1} a; /{/{a=0}' myfile.cfg` ignores the center piece but still yields the beginning portion:

```
if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*55555.*"){
```

I'd like to be able to look for certain patterns and ignore those I choose to ignore, e.g., find 5555 and 3333 and ignore that entire string, leaving 4444 alone. I initially thought something to the tune of:

```
awk '!/4444/ && /proto/{a=1} a; /{/{a=0}'
```

But its non functional. So I said hrmm perl loops:

```
if ($_[1] =~ /proto/) {
        if ($_[6] =~ /\}/) {
                        print "something\n";
                foreach (@_) {
                        print $_;
                }
                        print "something\n";
        }
}
```

*Buttttttt*... that wouldn't always work because some lines might be:

```
 if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*9999.*"){
         rewritehostport("10.10.10.2:1337");
         sl_send_reply("302", "Redirect");
         exit;
 }
```

Then I thought: `grep -wvf file_with_data_I_want_removed original_file >> new_file` But that defeats the purpose because I'd have to create file_with_data_I_want_removed

In essence, I want to say:

```
for [ this list of numbers (55555, 3333) ]

go into this_file if_number_exists remove line with number along with everything until the nearest curly bracket while ignoring the other ones

done



     if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*4444.*"){
             rewritehostport("10.10.10.2:1337");
             rewritehostport("10.20.30.2:2345");
             sl_send_reply("302", "Redirect");
             exit;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You were very close. Just rearranging the flag state should get you the desired output.

```
awk '/proto.*(55555|3333)/{a=0};a;/}/{a=1}' myfile.cfg
     if (uri=~"^proto:[+]*4444.*"){
             rewritehostport("10.10.10.2:1337");
             rewritehostport("10.20.30.2:2345");
             sl_send_reply("302", "Redirect");
             exit;
     }
```

- You disable the flag when your pattern that needs to be skipped is seen.
- You print the lines for which your flag is set.
- When you see the end of pattern enable the flag.

Comment: going to try both your suggestion and user000001's suggestion. This isn't a one time thing, I randomly get: remove 8888 or 99999 and 11111

Comment: @munkeyoto Sure, the other solution is good too. The only caveat I see is extra new lines in output and missing end brace (`}`) for each section.

Comment: @munkeyoto JS is right here, becayse I forgot to set The ORS. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the *record separator*, through the `RS` variable to `}` :

```
awk '!/4444/' RS='}' ORS='}' file
```